# How to move summation column programatically from Rows to column in pivot table [Powershell]

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot-table

I have been using powershell to generate a pivot table based on disk space report.Below is the part of the script which I am using to generate the pivot table

```
# Get sheets
$ws3 = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "DiskInformation"} #<------- Selects sheet 3


$xlPivotTableVersion12     = 3
$xlPivotTableVersion10     = 1
$xlCount                 = -4112
$xlDescending             = 2
$xlDatabase                = 1
$xlHidden                  = 0
$xlRowField                = 1
$xlColumnField             = 2
$xlPageField               = 3
$xlDataField               = 4    
$xlDirection        = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XLDirection]
# R1C1 means Row 1 Column 1 or "A1"
# R65536C5 means Row 65536 Column E or "E65536"

$range1=$ws3.range("A1")

$range1=$ws3.Range($range1,$range1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$range2=$ws3.range("H1")
$range2=$ws3.Range($range2,$range2.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$selection = $ws3.Range($range1, $range2)
#Write-Host "R2:"$range2
$PivotTable = $workbook.PivotCaches().Create($xlDatabase,$selection,$xlPivotTableVersion10)
$PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("R6C1","Tables1") | Out-Null 
[void]$ws3.Select()
#$ws3.Cells.Item(3,1).Select()
$workbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = $true 




$PivotFields = $ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Environment")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlColumnField

$PivotFields = $ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Used Capacity(GB)")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlDataField


$PivotFields = $ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Free Space(GB)")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlDataField


$PivotFields = $ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Farms/Classification")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField
```

Above script was taken from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850371/powershell-script-to-create-excel-pivot-table)

Above code works perfectly fine and it generates the report,however it generates a summation row "Values" which I need it to be in Columns section. Please find the screenshot below on how it looks currently

[image: StackOverFlow Site]

Can you please tell me how to move the auto generated field "Values" from Rows to column section?

Comment: Is there a `PivotField` object named `Values`?

Comment: @BenH I tried to generate pivot table manually through excel and found out that "`values`" field will be automatically generated whilst I add the fields "`Sum of Used Capacity` " & "`Sum of Free Space`". Can you please tell me how to traverse and get that field from the `PivotFields` object

Comment: Does `$ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Values")` return anything? What happens if you lookup by index? `$ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields(1)` etc.

Comment: @BenH `$ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Values")` throws an error `Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class` whereas the `$ws3.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields(1)`  returns a `System.__ComObject` object

Comment: @pnuts I am sorry, I didn't get you. can you please help me out a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future references, the following code worked for me

```
$PivotFields = $PivotTable.PivotTables("Tables1").DataPivotField
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlColumnField
$PivotFields.Position = 1
```