# How to create pivot table using export-excel function in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot

I have been using this [Github Link](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) to generate pivot chart. I have a pre-populated excel file[ File.xslx] and want to generate pivot table from that data. Below is the code snippet I have used.

```
Export-Excel -Path "Path/to/excel/file.xslx" -IncludePivotTable  -PivotRows "Row Name" -PivotData "Data Column"
```

However this throws the below error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
$isDataTypeValueType = $TargetData.GetType().name -match
```

Note: All required modules have been imported in the PS script

Update-1

I was able to recity the issue and now the code looks like

```
 $Imported = Import-XLSX -Path path\to\excel\file.xlsx -Header "Column-1","Column-2","Column-3","Column-4","Column-5","Column-6","Column-7","Column-8"


$Imported| Export-Excel -Path "Path/to/excel/file.xslx" -IncludePivotTable  -PivotRows "column-1" -PivotData @{"column-6"="sum";"column-7"="Sum"} -PivotColumns "column-2" -Show
```

And it is able to generate the pivot chart, but the issue is auto-generated Summantion column named "Values" is added to Rows section whereas I want it to be added to columns section. Can you please suggest on how I can go about it?

Update-2

I was able to resolve the value field issue now I want it to be moved to the top of the list in columns section

My code look like this as of now:

```
$Imported| Export-Excel -Path path\to\excel\file.xlsx -IncludePivotTable -PivotColumns "column-1" -PivotDataToColumn -PivotData @{"Column-2"="Sum";"column-3"="Sum"}  -PivotRows "column-4" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow   -Show
```

Currently the value field is getting display at the end basically low priority.Please tell me how to move it up?

Comment: Hi @sanketh, have you considered contacting Doug Finke who is the author of the cmdlets? You can do it directly in Github

Comment: @MickyBalladelli  Yes for the above situation , I have raised the concern with Doug [link]https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/199. However you might be able to help me with [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930833/how-to-move-summation-column-programatically-from-rows-to-column-in-pivot-table with this as I followed the steps given by you.