# Powershell - Create a Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, com, pivot-table

I have managed to open and adjust my file so far like this :

```
$Fichier = "XXXX\McAfeeWin10.csv"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($Fichier)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.item(1)

$objExcel.Visible = $true

$Range = $worksheet.UsedRange.Cells
$range.NumberFormat = "@"
$WorkSheet.Columns("A:C").AutoFit()
```

That file has 3 columns and looks like this :

[image]

Now all I want to do is create a pivot table with the settings like this :

Column = VerNoyau
Row = DATVer
Values = Poste

How can I do it?

I have found pivot table examples but they are very complex and involve creating the whole file. I'm working on an already existing file so I assume it would be simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850371/powershell-script-to-create-excel-pivot-table

Comment: When trying to figure out how to automate an Office product to do something, you should always record a macro of you doing it manually. Excel will automatically write the code to reproduce the steps that you did manually.

Comment: Very good tip Michael, didn't think of that. The code is in VB but can be transcribed well. However, when I record a macro and simply create the pivot table, it doesn't run complaining about errors. Oh well, for another day!